# Create view from multiple tables, combine values from multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, oracle, view, cursor

I have 3 tables as below:

**Area table:**

```
UserID | Area
---------------
  1    | 10001
  2    | 10002
  3    | 10003
```

**Info table:**

```
UserID | Info
-----------------
  1    |  U1_Info1
  1    |  U1_Info2
  1    |  U1_Info3
  2    |  U2_Info1
  3    |  U3_Info1
```

**Company table:**

```
UserID | Company
-----------------
  1    |  ComA
  2    |  ComB
  3    |  ComC
```

After that, I want group by UserID. My expected result as below:

```
UserID | Area  | Info1    | Info2    | Info3    | Company
----------------------------------------------------------
  1    | 10001 | U1_Info1 | U1_Info2 | U1_Info3 | ComA
  2    | 10002 | U2_Info1 |          |          | ComB
  3    | 10003 | U3_Info1 |          |          | ComC
```

User 3 doesn't have Info2 and Info3 so I set them = ' '.
Can I make a View like that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.User3 has U1_Info3 in the Info table, so why wouldn't that go in the Info3 column?. And what happens to UserID=2, Info=U1_Info2? Also, where does the UserID=1, Info2=U1_Info2 come from? That's not in the data, if you're relating Area to Info using UserID.

Comment: sr, my mistake. I mean User1 has 3 info: info1, info2 and Info3. I want to put them in a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10a94/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Area ( UserID, Area ) AS
          SELECT 1, 10001 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 10002 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 10003 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Info ( UserID, Info ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'U1_Info1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'U1_Info2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'U1_Info3' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'U2_Info1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'U3_Info1' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Company (UserID, Company ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'ComA' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'ComB' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'ComC' FROM DUAL;

CREATE VIEW TEST AS
SELECT A.UserID,
       MAX( A.Area    ) AS Area,
       MAX( CASE WHEN I.Info LIKE '%_Info1' THEN I.Info END ) AS Info1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN I.Info LIKE '%_Info2' THEN I.Info END ) AS Info2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN I.Info LIKE '%_Info3' THEN I.Info END ) AS Info3,
       MAX( C.Company ) AS Company
FROM   Area A
       INNER JOIN
       Company C
       ON ( A.UserID = C.UserID )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       Info I
       ON ( A.UserID = I.UserID )
GROUP BY
       A.UserID
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10a94/1/0)**:

```
| USERID |  AREA |    INFO1 |    INFO2 |    INFO3 | COMPANY |
|--------|-------|----------|----------|----------|---------|
|      1 | 10001 | U1_Info1 | U1_Info2 | U1_Info3 |    ComA |
|      2 | 10002 | U2_Info1 |   (null) |   (null) |    ComB |
|      3 | 10003 | U3_Info1 |   (null) |   (null) |    ComC |
```

Comment: I have problem on large data sets (Ex: 1 or 10 million records). It runs quietly slow, it takes 1.5 mins to 3 mins to excute. Any ideas to improve the performance of selecting data?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52072/1 is another way of doing it - probably not better as there are 3 full table scans on the `Info` table.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99ec2d/1 has a third way of doing it... profile them all and see if any one is better or if you can come up with a different option.

Comment: thank you very much, the third solution seems to work for me